Bulk rename a list of file names in windows based on inconsistent date naming scheme
I have a long list of files where various clerks named them inconsistently. They will all have names that begin with a series of numbers representing a 'date' followed by a description. Example
12-16-21 Report.pdf

2-12-22-Report.pdf

03-15-22_report.pdf

I'm looking for a Powershell script or BAT file that can parse these into a consistent format. At least the -date- portion so they sort properly. I don't care about the follow on descriptive text.
2021-12-16 Report.pdf

2022-02-12-Report.pdf

2022-03-15_report.pdf

I tried a Powershell script to rename based on Last Modified Date and found that those dates are not reliable. So I need help to see if there is a regular expression that can be used to parse out the initial numeric chars, reformat as yyyy-MM-dd-whatever, and rename.
$ParsedDate = [datetime]::MinValue;
$Path = "I:\Test";
Get-ChildItem -File -Path $Path -Recurse |
Where-Object { (-not [regex]::IsMatch($_.Name, "^\d{8}_",     [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::IgnoreCase)) -or (-not [datetime]::TryParseExact($_.Name.Substring(0, 8), "yyyyMMdd", [cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture, [System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles]::None, [ref] $ParsedDate)) } |
    ForEach-Object { Rename-Item -Path ($_.FullName) -NewName "$($_.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyyMMdd"))_$($_.Name)"; }

So... can someone provide some help with parsing the file name based on those initial numeric chars?

Here is my quick and dirty attempt to do it in Python (works with your example), you can probably port it to Powershell, or just use a similar regex:
import re, os

for file in os.listdir('.'):
    match = re.search(r'(^\d+).*?(\d+).*?(\d+)[^A-Za-z0-9]*(.*)', file)
    if match:
        m, d, y, s = match.groups()
        m, d, y = int(m), int(d), int(y) if len(y)>2 else 2000+int(y)
        new_name = f'{y:04}-{m:02}-{d:02} {s}'
        os.rename(file, new_name)


Outstanding! At the risk of asking for too much, is it possible to replace {s} with a literal string to make the remainder of each file consistent as well?, ie. '2020-01-23 Standard File Name.pdf'

Of course, either that, or add another line just before new_name = ... and put whatever you want in s directly. That's if you intend to just use Python, obviously (your original question asks for Bat or Powershell specifically), otherwise the only thing you'd likely use from here is the regex itself.

This fulfills my request. I've been meaning to begin working with Python. And already I can see why people like it.

Here is how to rename the file with Powershell cmdlets
 Get-ChildItem | Where-Object { $_.Name -match "^(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)(.+)$" } | foreach-object{
 
    $month = $Matches[1].PadLeft(2,"0")
    $day = $Matches[2].PadLeft(2,"0")
    $year = "{0:2000}" -f [int]$Matches[3]
    $other = $Matches[4]
 
    Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName ( $year + '-' + $month + '-' + $day + $other )
    
  }

